# Should I think about/take into account/manage memory consumption in Node server when I develop frontend in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am creating SPA web application - Yii2 API services that are consumed by the React SPA application. React application is served by the node server with the command `npm start`.

Question is - should I think about memory management in JavaScript code and how it impacts the memory consumption by the Noder server.

Some initial experiments show that my Node server (on Windows 10 workstation) consumes 200MB initilly, after first 15 page requests the consumption grows (as can be seen in the Task Manager) till 300MB and then each new page request increase memory approximately by 1MB, but after some time the memory is recovered and consumption decreases and stabilises around 300MB.

Is this normal behaviour?

My guess was that I should think only about what happens in client browser, node should forget everything from the moment when the page is served to the client.

I have this question because my Node server broke down during development time and I am afraid that it can happen in production as well:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[14416:00000248F3E072F0] 25742472 ms: Mark-sweep 1394.1 (1448.4) -> 1394.0 (1448.4) MB, 112.2 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[14416:00000248F3E072F0] 25742582 ms: Mark-sweep 1394.0 (1448.4) -> 1391.3 (1413.4) MB, 110.4 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[14416:00000248F3E072F0] 25742692 ms: Mark-sweep 1391.3 (1413.4) -> 1391.3 (1412.4) MB, 110.4 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 00000156F9D25529 <JSObject>
    2: replace(this=00000188823C00B9 <Very long string[570801]>,000001E83CD62109 <String[32]: var HTML_WEBPACK_PLUGIN_RESULT =>,000003385EA02431 <String[0]: >)
    3: /* anonymous */ [C:\xampp3\htdocs\...\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\index.js:224] [bytecode=000001E83CD60D69 offset=39](this=000001D78CCEC789 <HtmlWebpackPlugin map = 000000AF60CBA179>,compilation=0000009A874EC2D1 <Tapabl...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::DecodeWrite
 2: node_module_register
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString
 6: v8::internal::Smi::SmiPrint
 7: v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts
 8: v8::internal::SlicedString::SlicedStringGet
 9: v8::internal::AsmJsScanner::IsNumberStart
10: 0000036A84D043C1
```